# How does RequestJS actually process its callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am arguably a pretty big noob in NodeJS so maybe this is obvious to anyone else except me ;)
Reading https://github.com/mikeal/request/blob/master/request.js#L71 I dont get how the callback parameter is passed along (https://github.com/mikeal/request#requestoptions-callback). I guess it has something to do with the `arguments` that are processed in `Request.prototype.init`, but when doing a short test I could not reproduce the behaviour:

```
var test = function(a) {this.init(a);}
test.prototype.init = function(a){
  for(var i in arguments) console.log(arguments[i]);
}
new test('bla', 'blub');
```

results in

```
bla
{}
```

so I really dont get how exactly the callback is set up and I would love to find out.

Comment: This is interesting. **I'm not sure how**, but I wonder if it has to do with this line: `stream.Stream.call(this)`

Comment: I consider myself an advanced JS developer and I can't see what's going on, still looking...

Comment: @JuanMendes It looks like they access `self.callback` in the `init` method. Which seems that `this[i] = options[i]` is setting it in the constructor. But `options` is always the first param (or a new object), and nothing seems to look at a second parameter or argument, so I can't see how it's picking up the argument

Comment: @Ian I was thinking the same thing, the code seems to indicate that you need to call it like `request( {url: '', callback: function(){}} )` since it copies the options into `this`

Comment: @JuanMendes Exactly, that's the only way it seems that it would work. But nothing in the documentation shows that, and points to a second argument...weird

Comment: Perhaps the documentation is referring to a different version of the code?

Comment: @Ian when calling `stream.Stream.call` you would have to explicitly pass it the `arguments` array, otherwise there is no way it could access the 2nd parameter.

Comment: @levi I understand that, I have no idea how that would pass the arguments/param, but I thought there was something magical

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual function that is exported when you require `request` is a [wrapper function](https://github.com/mikeal/request/blob/master/index.js#L40) from the package `index.js` file, which initializes the options object, and then uses it to instantiate an instance of `Request`. This should be evident when you consider that no `new` keyword is required to utilize the function, even though it is clearly a constructor.

Comment: Nice! I had a feeling it was some sort of wrapper, but I didn't think to look in a different file (couldn't find anything in the same file)

Comment: aaaah *facepalm* ok, that explains it ... I should have read the package.json and realized I was looking into the wrong file ^^